# Is Stack Overflow a proper place to earn reputation for a good job?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

Is Stack Overflow a proper place to earn reputation for a good job? I look through the questions and it seems to me that we have a lot of artificial questions that were asked by people who actually know the answer.

Comment: how much reputation do you need to buy a good job?  what can i get for 386 rep?

Comment: i'm wondering about your "artificial questions" note.  i don't think SOFU has ever declared *"not knowing the answer"* a requirement for posting a question.

Answer (score 12):

I would say that SO isn't a good place if your main motivation is to get reputation to get a good job. The motivation should be helping people - and it's pretty obvious when that isn't the case (IMO). Having said that, between SO and SO Careers, it can certainly be a *benefit* when looking for a new job.

Personally I haven't seen much in the way of clearly artificial questions - could you give examples?

Comment: Put some to this thread afterwards

Comment: A lot of questions is without selected answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438138/size-of-object-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437768/how-to-call-jsp-file-from-java

Comment: @Artic that is probably not down to the questions being "artificial", but askers simply not accepting an answer. I don't think this is representative of the question base on SO in general.

Comment: This questions is always looks clever and popular and easy to google

Comment: @Artic well, they are badly worded questions but not the worst I've seen. They are not a pleasant phenomenon, but thanks to the immense numbers of visitors even they usually draw usable answers, which took some time for me to get used to. There is no obligation to answer poorly worded questions. What exactly is your problem with them?

Comment: @Pekka: Do you have any evidence that those questions are being used to effectively farm reputation?

Comment: @Jon I am not saying those questions are being used to farm reputation, am I? @Artic is.

Comment: @Pekka: Sorry, that was meant to be to Artic to start with. Doh.

Comment: @Jon thought so, no problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439315/efficient-way-to-get-the-most-used-keys-in-a-hashmap-java

Comment: Another one that was discussed a lot of times on dev forums.

And when person came with his badly stiled code with a lot of mistakes they put him downvotes.

Comment: Example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439272/how-can-i-read-the-value-of-a-radio-button-in-javascript/2439292#2439292

Comment: Just want to call every you to put some moderation to vote system. If i were this man who asked this question i would have thought this is not a proper place to ask questions for beginner, only for mature wolves.

Comment: @Artic SO is by definition the proper place for both. High-level questions are mixed with total newbie ones, which is one of the things that makes it so nice IMO. If you feel the presence of questions like the ones you link to could tarnish your reputation, then maybe SO is not the place for you. Because those questions will keep on coming. :) By the way, I just noted that the one downvote on that question you link to is mine.

Comment: Pekka: completely agree with you. Just cant understand thous who upvote(think "cool") questions like on dev contests and downvote(dislike) real "simple" questions.

Comment: Contest questions does not bring help to anyone. People just show how smart they are. May be way out is to make separate thread or something like that for people who like to show them as topcoders.

Comment: @Artic, please note that you're still commenting to Jon's answer. (And please give Stack Overflow et al a bit more than three days to get used to.)

Comment: @Arjan I think our squatting in Jon's answer is already so beyond the pale that we may just as well finish the discussion in here :) I second your second point though.

Answer (score 5):

If you start participating on SO with the goal of earning reputation to get a job, you will probably get frustrated quickly. Gaining reputation is often an arbitrary process, and a sole focus on rep will usually result in some kind of negative feedback from the community. Plus, it's entirely possible that your SO reputation will be shrugged upon when trying to get a job, simply because people don't know the site or don't value it.

But if you participate on SO out of interest for your area of expertise, to converse with fellow developers, or to stay up to date in your technology, and if you bring along solid knowledge in your field, your participation will very likely, over some time, amount to a track record (including reputation points) that can be beneficial when looking for a job. It may even land you a job when you are especially active in a field, and point out to be looking for work in your profile - you never know.