# Make some separation of "please help" and "do you know" questions

Tags: feature-request

Make some new thread for contest questions. Think that there two type of questions in SO "please help" and "do you know". Think could be separated somehow. Couse there is some issue with reputation of questioners and answerers.

Comment: Thread? This not being a forum, that would be yet another web site?

Comment: Call it as you like to call. Category, tag, some kind of separation. I'm not a specialist in terminology. Just try to understand my idea. If it is fool - ok, if not try to support it somehow.

Comment: Rather than asking people to try to understand, I propose you clarify a bit. Or look for duplicate requests here: Stack Overflow has been around a long time, so I kind of doubt that after only three days you come up with something that hasn't been asked before, if such change were required. There's an "edit" link underneath your question!

Comment: I fail to see either the distinction you are trying to make *or* the what would be gained by adding another layer of complexity tp the sites. ::envisions the need for a "migrate to other thread-thingy" tool::

Comment: @Arjan, come on.

Comment: (@D_N, I don't know what your "come on" implies, but just for the record: I was not trying to be unfriendly, but truly did not understand what exactly "Make some new thread for contest questions" was supposed to mean in the context of SO. Still, I forgot a *Welcome to Stack Overflow!* So, @Artic, Welcome! And enjoy!)

Comment: @Artic: can you provide links to a few example questions that you feel fall into each category, and expand a bit on why the distinction would be helpful?

Comment: Ether: look at this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42154/is-so-proper-place-to-earn-reputation-for-a-good-job

Comment: Arjan van Bentem : thank you. You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you participate in the site for a while first.

I'm quite sure that despite all shortcomings (I think you have a point with your observations and some of the examples you present in your [other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42154/is-so-proper-place-to-earn-reputation-for-a-good-job)) you will find that, while not perfect, by and large, everyday "business" is still quite okay on Stack Overflow and its sister sites: People get questions answered, and people can give good answers to questions. People get support, broaden their knowledge, and are having fun while at it.

Now sometimes, stupid or carelessly worded questions will get reputation unjustly. Sometimes, wrong or shallow answers will get reputation unjustly. Sometimes, a shallow answer will get unjustly accepted, while your deeply researched answer that you put half an hour's work (and five years' expertise) into does not get one upvote. That's why it's good not to be too focused on reputation, and not to take it too seriously. If you participate in the site, reputation is something that will accumulate itself.

Comment: My point of view will change with time but I think idea is quite fresh and it is not good thing to be so conservative.

Comment: @Artic At the moment, what I see is a newcomer who would like a community with 4.5 million unique visitors to *somehow* change the way it deals with answers because he thinks the current way is somehow stupid, and is too lenient with noobs. That is far, far away from a fresh idea to even have a favourable or unfavourable opinion on.

Comment: Just turn my words upside-down. Lets wait and see what will happen in a year.